# Which one is odd one out?

Tags: odd-one-out

This question was asked in CSIR June 16.

Out of the following which one is the odd one out?

- Cone
- Torus
- Sphere
- Ellipsoid

Well in my point of view, cone, sphere and ellipsoid are topologically equivalent. So, answer should be torus. Am I right?

But some where I found answer cone since all other are 3-D representation of a circle.

Which one is correct?

Comment: There can be many different explanations, for example: cone is the only one that has corners

Comment: Yeah! that is why i am confused! is my explanation right ?

Comment: It is. cone, sphere and ellipsoid are all a circle topologically, while torus isn't.

Comment: Torus can also be odd, because it's the only one without letter 'e' in it. As I told, many solutions, depending on your perspective :)

Comment: No! Sphere and Torus are not topologically equivalent .

Comment: This is question is too broad and can be primarily opinion based.

Comment: At first, this question seems too broad. However, it is presented as `I got a different answer. Why?` and that can be answered - as it already has been below - with `You didn't. There are many good answers.` This is a question *about* puzzles and not a puzzle in-and-of-itself, which fits well with Puzzling's original intent.

Comment: a cone has more circular cross sections than an ellipsoid or a torus.

Comment: @GintasK sphere has also got corners, an infinite number of corners.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The topologically equivalent explanation makes sense to me, since all the objects except the torus can be transformed into eachother.

On the other hand, as mentioned, there can be many different explanations.

The cone is the only one with a flat surface.
The ellipsoid is the only one that can't be described using only circles.

But if you're a topologist, you can't distinguish between a teacup and a donut, and in this case the torus would seem like the odd one out.

(See here: https://books.google.dk/books?id=Kgnzwq62xv8C&pg=PT188&lpg=PT188&dq=donut+teacup&source=bl&ots=43lGVSh0zS&sig=27Nl0AaIFEabtiknBbKkWuGgkdg&hl=da&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRoojwuM_NAhUG_ywKHeGFDFQQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=donut%20teacup&f=false)

Answer (score 18):

The *cone* is the odd one out because it is the only one that isn't smooth and the only one that's of infinite extent (at least if you're a mathematician).

The *torus* is the odd one out because it's the only one that isn't simply connected.

The *sphere* is the odd one out because it's the only one on which euclidean symmetries act transitively (i.e., all its points are the same).

The *ellipsoid* is the odd one out because it's the only one on which some but not all points are umbilical points (i.e., points near to which the surface "looks like a sphere" in a certain sense).

Comment: Technically an open cone is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$, since it is an open subset. What is not a smooth submanifold, however, is the surface of that cone, in particular it is non-smooth exactly at the tip.

Comment: I was taking them all to be the surfaces.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative "All of the above" answer.

Since:

```
     Cone  cone
    Torus  torus
   Sphere  sphere / sphere   
Ellipsoid  ellipsoid / ellipsoid
```

We can say:

```
     this | is the only one containing...
----------+------------------------------
     Cone |         the pronoun one
    Torus |     1 other pronoun
   Sphere |    2 unique pronouns
Ellipsoid |  1 repeated pronoun
```

Comment: "I" is a pronoun that occurs twice in "Ellipsoid".

Comment: D'oh, how did **I** miss it, it's there twice!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe

> the torus,

because the other three are

> [quadric surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric#Euclidean_space).

Answer (score 1):

Sphere is the odd one out because it is the only one that does not contain the letter 'o'.

As you can see, the question is completely ambiguous.